# Why does caffeine make me sleep better?

Tags: medications, sleep, neurology, caffeine, sleep-deprivation

I have self-administered around `4 mg/kg` of caffeine (peroral), and around two hours later I fell asleep, being just a little bit sleep-deprived.

After around five hours of sleep I found myself awake, in awesome mood and I did not want to sleep at all.

It was not a one-time thing, I did notice it before, but this is the first time it really caught my attention. **What is even happening here?**

<sup>P. S. Plase notice I drink a lot of coffee, so there might or might not be a slight tolerance. I do not have any sleep-related health issues. I have zero education in subject areas. Also, excuse me for my English.</sup>

Comment: Just a heads up, if you "drink a lot of coffee" you wouldn't have a "slight" tolerance, but a full tolerance since tolerance occurs within 4 days for blood pressure and 7-12 days for neurological affects, see studies here: https://health.stackexchange.com/a/16996/809

Answer (score 6):

[Caffeine Absorption](http://www.caffeineinformer.com/caffeine-absorption)  ***Caffeine Capsules -    200mg - 84-120 minutes***

So maybe you took the caffeine, were already tired so you napped(2 hours or 120 minutes) just as it was kicking in full blown and then woke up a little later with the effects already in action, but not sleeping the full amount.

Since the capsules take longer to kick in than liquids and gums, you fell asleep before it fully woke you up. And since some say that caffeine works less if you are [caffeine tolerant](http://www.caffeineinformer.com/caffeine-tolerance) then this may explain.

---

### Other

According to [Mens Fitness](http://www.mensfitness.com/life/why-does-caffeine-make-me-tired) it could be a variation in your genes (CYP1A2 genes) that show how you metabolize caffeine. There is a test for that apparently, but I don't know how accurate that is.

- [7 Gene Test](https://www.nutrigenomix.com/tests-available)

> The 7 gene test consists of a panel of seven genetic markers that
>   enable your healthcare professional to provide you with personalized
>   nutritional recommendations based on your DNA. This test determines
>   how your body responds to vitamin C, folate, whole grains, omega-3
>   fats, saturated fat, sodium and caffeine.

But then again, there appears a lot of reasons to why caffeine makes some people sleep:

- [Increases Insulin Response.](http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/abs/10.1139/y01-026#.Vu-eMeIrLIV) Does not happen for everybody, but the increased insulin could make you tired. [It doesn't appear to have much of a affect though.](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/type-2-diabetes/expert-answers/blood-sugar/faq-20057941)

> For most young, healthy adults, caffeine doesn't appear to noticeably
>   affect blood sugar (glucose) levels, and consumption up to 400
>   milligrams a day appears to be safe.

- Some also say it has to do with vasoconstriction and dehydration due to diuretic effects of coffee.

***The above other reasons don't seem to be the case in your case, but they are interesting possibilities.***